# PHP Codeigniter parsing array ( [0] => test2 [1] => test1)

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, parsing

i need help about how to parsing this array in codeigniter

array ( [0] => test0 [1] => test1)

in the CodeIgniter user guide i found this:

```
    {blog_entries}
            <h5>{title}</h5>
            <p>{body}</p>
    {/blog_entries}
```

Thats works if the array is like:

```
$data = array(
    'blog_title'   => 'My Blog Title',
    'blog_heading' => 'My Blog Heading',
    'blog_entries' => array(
            array('title' => 'Title 1', 'body' => 'Body 1'),
            array('title' => 'Title 2', 'body' => 'Body 2'),
            array('title' => 'Title 3', 'body' => 'Body 3'),
            array('title' => 'Title 4', 'body' => 'Body 4'),
            array('title' => 'Title 5', 'body' => 'Body 5')
    ));
```

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/parser.html?highlight=parsing

But I receive array like this from one API:

```
    $data = array(
    'blog_title'   => 'My Blog Title',
    'blog_heading' => 'My Blog Heading',
    'blog_entries' => array(
            array('0' => 'Title 1', 'body' => 'Body 1'),
            array('1' => 'Title 2', 'body' => 'Body 2'),
            array('2' => 'Title 3', 'body' => 'Body 3'),
            array('3' => 'Title 4', 'body' => 'Body 4'),
            array('4' => 'Title 5', 'body' => 'Body 5')
    ));
```

**How i can parse it? or how i can transform numbers [0,1,2,3] to [title,title,title,title]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do a simple remaping function:

```
$out = array();
foreach ($blog_entries as $index => $array) {
    $out[] = array('title' => $array[$index], 'body' => $array['body']);
}
```

Sample Output:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(7) "Title 1"
    ["body"]=>
    string(6) "Body 1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(7) "Title 2"
    ["body"]=>
    string(6) "Body 2"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(7) "Title 3"
    ["body"]=>
    string(6) "Body 3"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(7) "Title 4"
    ["body"]=>
    string(6) "Body 4"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(7) "Title 5"
    ["body"]=>
    string(6) "Body 5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The first parameter contains the name of the view file (in this
>   example the file would be called blog_template.php), and the second
>   parameter contains an associative array of data to be replaced in the
>   template.

```
$data = array(
'blog_title'   => 'My Blog Title',
'blog_heading' => 'My Blog Heading',
'blog_entries' => array(
        array('0' => 'Title 1', 'body' => 'Body 1'),
        array('1' => 'Title 2', 'body' => 'Body 2'),
        array('2' => 'Title 3', 'body' => 'Body 3'),
        array('3' => 'Title 4', 'body' => 'Body 4'),
        array('4' => 'Title 5', 'body' => 'Body 5')
));

foreach ($data['blog_entries'] as &$arr)
{
    foreach ($arr as $k => $v)
    {
        if (is_numeric($k))
        {
            $arr['title'] = $v;
            unset($arr[$k]);
        }
    }
    $arr = array_reverse($arr);
}

echo '<pre>', var_dump($data);exit;
```

But you should be aware of eventual changes of structure of `$data` array. So if your api would export one more element with numeric key to that array, this code would be broken probably. You can check and test it though.